# How do I update my Python Google Sheet API credentials code to avoid package depreciation?

Tags: python, authentication, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

The [Google Sheets API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) currently uses [deprecated packages](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) in its example code, where the use of [`oauth2client`](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) and [`httplib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httplib2/) rather than [`google-auth`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [`google-auth-oauthlib`](http://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (or maybe `google-auth`?) is outdated or soon to be.

How do I rewrite this code to use these new libraries in a way that best anticipates their current state and the eventual move to `google-auth`, etc.? In particular, is there a simple reimplementation of retrieval, storage, and use of credentials in the quickstart (below) that brings it up to date?

---

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, 'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl =  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)
    # etc. ...
```

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If it was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer? I prepared the sample script for the Quickstart of Sheets API.

- In this sample, it supposes below.

  - Sheet API is enabled
  - You have a `client_secret.json`.
- In this sample, at first, refresh token is retrieved using authorization code. The refresh token is saved to `sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json`. After 1st run, the access token is retrieved by the refresh token.
- In this sample, cell values are retrieved from spreadsheet.

### Sample script :

```
import copy
import json
import os
import pprint

import google.oauth2.credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'


def get_authenticated_service():
    credential_path = os.path.join("./", 'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')
    if os.path.exists(credential_path):
        with open(credential_path, 'r') as f:
            credential_params = json.load(f)
        credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
            credential_params["access_token"],
            refresh_token=credential_params["refresh_token"],
            token_uri=credential_params["token_uri"],
            client_id=credential_params["client_id"],
            client_secret=credential_params["client_secret"]
        )
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
        credentials = flow.run_console()
        with open(credential_path, 'w') as f:
            p = copy.deepcopy(vars(credentials))
            del p["expiry"]
            json.dump(p, f, indent=4)
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)


def spreadsheets_get(service):
    spreadsheetId = "### spreadsheet ID ###"
    rangeName = "Sheet1!a1:a10"
    results = service.spreadsheets().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
        ranges=rangeName
    ).execute()
    pp.pprint(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    service = get_authenticated_service()
    spreadsheets_get(service)
```

#### Note :

- In order to save `credentials`, it was required to use `oauth2client.file`. So I prepared the sample script without using `oauth2client.file`. If you want to use `oauth2client.file`, please modify it.
- I think that [Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) may be also updated in the near future.

### References :

References I refered to prepare this sample script are as follows.

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app)

  - There is a sample script for python.
- [User Guide](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)
- [google.oauth2.credentials module](http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.